# Error Code: 502 Proxy Error. The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator

Tags: apache, http, proxy

I have installed apache HTTP server and after when i browse to localhost i am getting this error. Apache server is started. Port is configured to 80 and seems to be no one use it. I can't figure out what is the problem. Can someone?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're routing your localhost traffic through your upstream gateway proxy. The upstream gateway proxy refuses to send the traffic back, either because "localhost" has a different meaning to it, or because it's trying to prevent a security threat called "proxy bounceback."  What URL are you using to access your site? Put that URL's hostname in your proxy exemption list.

Comment: That's might the reason i checked my proxy setting "Bypass proxy settings for local address" in the browser settings and it works for me. Thanks for the answer ericlaw.

Answer (score 1):

Open the ISA server2006 and create a role and allow networks internal to allow internal and external .And restart the isa services .It will work fine

I tried this and it is working fine.